# EF Core empty migration issue

Tags: entity-framework-migrations, ef-core-2.1

I am using .Net Core 2.1 and EF Core 2.1. I successfully created 2 tables with EF Code First Migrations and dotnet CLI also seeded data into it. However when I try to add a new model Feature, and run the migration, the file generated has empty Up() and Down() methods and there is no entry in the EF_MigrationsHistory table of Database and the modelSnapshot.cs file also doesn't contain any references to the Feature model. I cross checked the ApplicationDbContext to see if I accidentally missed the declaration of the model in the class but I hadn't. I am not sure of the issue. Can anyone help me out with this? Posting the codes from my project:

**Feature.cs**

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
namespace ProjectName.Models
{
  public class Feature
  {
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
  }
}
```

**ApplicationDbContext.cs**

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using ProjectName.Models;

namespace ProjectName.Persitance{
public class ApplicationDbContext: DbContext{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> context)
            : base(context){ }

    public DbSet<Make> Makes { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Feature> Features { get; set; }
   }
}
```

**20180906063933_AddFeature.cs(Migration File):**

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations;

namespace ProjectName.Migrations
{
    public partial class AddFeature : Migration
    {
        protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {

        }

        protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

**ApplicationDbContextModelSnapshot.cs:**

```
// <auto-generated />
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ValueConversion;
using Application.Persitance;

namespace Application.Migrations
{
    [DbContext(typeof(ApplicationDbContext))]
    partial class ApplicationDbContextModelSnapshot : ModelSnapshot
    {
        protected override void BuildModel(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
    #pragma warning disable 612, 618
            modelBuilder
            .HasAnnotation("ProductVersion", "2.1.2-rtm-30932")
            .HasAnnotation("Relational:MaxIdentifierLength", 128)
            .HasAnnotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", 
              SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn);

            modelBuilder.Entity("Application.Models.Make", b =>
            {
                b.Property<int>("Id")
                    .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
                    .HasAnnotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", 
                    SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn);

                b.Property<string>("Name")
                    .IsRequired()
                    .HasMaxLength(255);

                b.HasKey("Id");

                b.ToTable("Makes");
            });

        modelBuilder.Entity("Application.Models.Model", b =>
            {
                b.Property<int>("Id")
                    .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
                    .HasAnnotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", 
                      SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn);

                b.Property<int>("MakeId");

                b.Property<string>("Name")
                    .IsRequired()
                    .HasMaxLength(255);

                b.HasKey("Id");

                b.HasIndex("MakeId");

                b.ToTable("Models");
            });

            modelBuilder.Entity("Application.Models.Model", b =>
            {
                b.HasOne("Application.Models.Make", "Make")
                    .WithMany("Models")
                    .HasForeignKey("MakeId")
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
            });
     #pragma warning restore 612, 618
     }
   }
 }
```

**__EFMigrationsHistory DB Image:**

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Usually this happens when you include `context.Database.EnsureCreated();` in your seed data file. This method doesn't allow to create a migrations table and cannot be used with migrations. You need to remove migrations with `Remove-Migration` command or delete the Migration folder and the database in your server and create new migration. Check [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-rp/migrations?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio) for better understanding.

Comment: I am sure I don't have anything like this written in my code, I have checked it many times.

Comment: In run button chose the project name not IIS Express and se the error in cmd.

Comment: Actually I am using VS Code editor and not VS Studio. Also I don't see any error. The migrations just run fine but the problem is they return empty file all the time I run.

Comment: run the application from cmd. It must show some kind of error in cmd after execution because when create an new table or seed data you can see the success or the fail of EF.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue. The `Up` method was empty despite cleaning the migrations folder and running `dotnet ef migrations add Initial` multiple times.

The solution in my case was to change the DbSet properties and add `virtual` to each of them.

Instead of

```
public DbSet<Make> Makes { get; set; }
```

try

```
public virtual DbSet<Make> Makes { get; set; }
```